# python Only handle OSError Errno 13 (permission denied)

Tags: python, exception

I am migrating an application to python3 but there are legacy systems that cannot be upgraded yet using python2.

I have the application that needs to update a cache file but if for some reason the user launching the application cannot read/update the cache. it is no big deal and he can just query the db again instead of using the cache.

I would like therefore pass the permission denied exception on python2 it is an OSError [Errno 13].
on python3 i use PermissionError so that is okay. I assume that this exception will only catch the errno 13.

this is what i have on python3

```
for filename in os.listdir(cache_dir):
     try:
       if filename.endswith('.cache'):
           os.remove(os.path.join(cache_dir, filename))
     Except PermissionError: 
            pass
     Except OSError:
            #handle all other errors
```

how can I mimic the same on python2 so that only Errno 13 is `passed` and not anything else?  eg I can pass if its a permission denied but not if the fs is read-only or the disk is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only `OSError` to catch, but you can check the error number contained in the exception.

```
import errno


for filename in os.listdir(cache_dir):

    # Keep the try block as focused as possible.
    if not filename.endswith('.cache'):
        continue
    fname = os.path.join(cache_dir, filename)

    try:
        os.remove(fname)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EACCES:
            # handle other errors
```

Use the `errno` module, because error numbers vary from one operating system to another.

Comment: EPERM means operation not permitted whereas Eaccess means permission denied according to http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno 
when i test the code i get 13 as e.errno. so i should use EACESS right?

Comment: Probably, I didn't look too closely :)

Comment: Actually, it seems it's a little ambiguous. `PermissionError` is documented as corresponding to *both* error numbers. But in this case `EACCES` does seem to be the right one.