# How to catch only Errno13

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I want to catch errno 13 permission denied separately from other errors. I have the following code

```
import shutil

try:
    print 'Copying files...'
    shutil.copytree('C:/Users/' + userName
                    + '/AppData/Roaming/Test/test1/', 'C:/Users/'
                    + userName + '/Desktop/test')
    print 'Success!'
except WindowsError, e:

# EXCEPTION HANDLING

    if e.winerror == 2 or e.winerror == 3:
        print 'Requested file does not exist.'
    elif e.winerror == 5:
        print 'You do not have the required privileges to make changes to this file.'
        print 'One of the following solutions may work:'
        print '   >The file might be open in another location, close the file and try again.'
        print '   >Try to run the program as administrator.'
    else:
        print 'Unexpected exception occurred. Please copy the following exception and send it to test at test@test.com'

# This block is executed every time I get err13

        print e
        quit()
except Exception, e:
    print 'Unexpected exception occured. Please copy the following exception and send it to test at test@test.com'
    print e
    quit()
```

I tried a bunch of different ways but it also ends up executing the marked else block.

**Output of above code (modified):**

```
Creating copy...
[('C:/Us.....', 'C:/Users/.....', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/User.....'")]
```

Edit 1:

```
import shutil
import errno
errno.EACCES

try:
    shutil.copytree('C:/bla/bla', 'C:/bla/bla')
except WindowsError as e:
    if e.winerror == 2 or e.winerror == 3:
        print("error 2 or 3")
    elif e.winerror == 5:
        print("error 5")
    else:
        print("unexpected stuff")

**except PermissionError as err:
    print("permission error")**

except Exception as e:
    print("unexpected that is not win error or permissionerror")
    quit()
```

Tried the above code but it executes else: print("unexpected stuff") and never reaches PermissionError block.

Comment: did you added condition for checking error no 13?

Comment: you can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614796/python-only-handle-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: Also, [python 2 is dead](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Don't use it  (unless you have a _really_ good reason to).

Comment: If you are strict to keep using Python2 (at least for python 2.7) you could check if the error is type 13, ```elif e.winerror == 13``` [Python Docs - errno.EACCES](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/errno.html?highlight=errno%20eacces#errno.EACCES)

Comment: @FrancoGil I thought I was using python3. 
elif e.winerror == 13 doesnt work unfortunately. It still executes the else block.

Comment: @deadshot I tried `elif e.winerror == 13` but it doesn't work. As for the solution you linked, if I create another except block for PermissionError, IDE tells me code is unreachable.

Comment: @JatinderBrar observing the print statement you are not using python3 ```print 'Hello'``` is a syntax error on python3 interpreter. Let us know what is the python interpreter that you are using on this script. If is python2 I will remove my answer.

Comment: @FrancoGil oh just realised, I edited the code for question but the actual code is all python3. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Python docs and assuming that you are using Python3:

```
import errno

errno.EACCES
# 13
```

[Python3 Error - errno.EACCES](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html#errno.EACCES)

> This error is mapped to the exception PermissionError.

Based on python docs:

[Exceptions - PermissionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PermissionError)

> Raised when trying to run an operation without the adequate access rights - for example filesystem permissions. Corresponds to errno EACCES and EPERM.

How to catch a PermissionError exeption?

```
try:
    raise PermissionError
except PermissionError as err:
    # Expose a cordial message to the user or client
    pass
```

Comment: I tried the following but it still ends up executing the unexpected error block. The permission error is highlighted as unreachable code.

`try:  
    shutil.copytree('C:/blabla', 'C:/Users/blabla')  
except WindowsError as e:  
    if e.winerror == 2 or e.winerror == 3:  
        print("error 2 or 3")
    elif e.winerror == 5:
        print("error 5")
    else:
        print("unexpected stuff")
except PermissionError as err:
    print("permission error")`